# Set property of one control from the HierarchicalDataTemplate of another

Tags: wpf, datagrid, treeview, binding

I've got a viewmodel like so:

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    public abstract string Header { get; }
    public abstract IEnumerable<ViewModelBase> Nodes { get; }
    public abstract IEnumerable GridData { get; }

    // following are hooked up to PropertyChanged event in the standard way
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public bool IsExpanded { get; set; }
}
```

This represents the nodes in a TreeView. Now, whenever the selecteditem changes, I want the selected item's `GridData` property to be copied to a separate DataGrid's ItemSource property.

I've got a DataTrigger Setter that should be doing what I want:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" />

<TreeView Name="treeView" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:ViewModelBase}" ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="dataGrid" Property="DataContext" Value="{Binding GridData}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

However, this is giving an error 'Cannot find the Trigger target 'dataGrid'. How do I get this working, and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the `dataGrid` name cannot be found is that you are trying to access an element that is located in a different [Name Scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659.aspx), meaning that elements inside a data template cannot "see" elements that are outside that template.

To fix that you could do the following. You will need another view model for your `UserControl` (or a `Window`, whatever contains you `TreeView` and `DataGrid`). Lets call it `MyTreeViewModel`:

```
public class MyTreeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged // Better to implement this interface in some base class for all your view models
{
    private TreeItemViewModelBase _selectedNode;

    public IEnumerable<TreeItemViewModelBase> TopLevelNodes
    {
        get { yield return new TopLevelTreeNodeViewModel(); // Subclass of your base class for tree nodes (ViewModelBase) }
    }

    public TreeItemViewModelBase SelectedNode
    {
        get { return _selectedNode; }
        set
        {
            _selectedNode = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedNode");
        }
    }
}
```

Set an instance of this view model as `DataContext` of your `UserControl` that contains you `TreeView` and `DataGrid`. Then, you XAML will look like this:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedNode.GridData}" />

<TreeView Name="treeView" ItemsSource="{Binding TopLevelNodes}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:ViewModelBase}" ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

Then, you need to modify you ViewModelBase (I suggest rename it to `TreeItemViewModelBase` to avoid confusion):

```
public abstract class TreeItemViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isSelected;

    public TreeItemViewModelBase(MyTreeViewModel parentViewModel)
    {
        ParentViewModel = parentViewModel;
    }

    public abstract string Header { get; }
    public abstract IEnumerable<TreeItemViewModelBase> Nodes { get; }
    public abstract IEnumerable GridData { get; }

    public MyTreeViewModel ParentViewModel { get; private set; }

    // following are hooked up to PropertyChanged event in the standard way
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected");

            if (_isSelected) {
               ParentViewModel.SelectedNode = this;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsExpanded { get; set; }
}
```

As you see, it maintains a reference to the parent view model and whenever `IsSelected` is set to `true` it sets itself as `SelectedNode` on the parent view model, which triggers data binding on `DataGrid`s `ItemsSource` to refresh.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I normally would raise an event on the child and let the parent handle the selected item relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my usual solution for such situation:

1. First of all I always have a VM which contains collection of root nodes. Let's name it `RootVM`.  This VM contains root nodes and `SelectedNode` property.
2. Your grid view datasource should be bound to `RootVM.SelectedNode.GridData`
3. Then you have to bind selected node in tree to the `SelectedNode` property. The problem here is that it cannot be bound directly (`SelectedItem` property in treeview is readonly), but this can be solved. I prefer to use attached behavior for this, some prefer inheriting treeView - it's up to you.

This seems to be a good way how to get it working.